# Mac Shortcut Key Making Sound - What is it doing? (Or not doing)

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am using a Mac (OSX 10.15 Catalina).

Recently I have found that using the shortcut ( **control** ) + ( **/** ) causes my mac to make a system alert sound as if something was tried but didn't work...

The problem I have is that I can't determine what is assigned this shortcut and what it is trying to do (unsuccessfully it seems).

I could probably live with it except that I use Apps Script IDE and the shortcut is useful there for commenting/commenting code.

I have even paid for KeyCue but that hasn't uncovered anything...

Comment: There's no native key command with only Control & [any other] key. Anything that uses that must be application-specific. Stack Exchange uses it for some markdown formatting commands too. In a browser, for instance, it won't generate the error, but won't do anything unless you're in an area that can use it. Finder, however, will generate the error beep.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be like looking for a needle in a haystack. I was just wondering if there is a way of determining which application may have been activated?

Comment: I don't understand. It isn't activated, that's why it beeps. If you check system prefs>keyboard>shortcuts> you can look down the lists to see if anything has been manually set - but if it's set, it wouldn't beep.

Comment: Sorry won't terminology you are right is not activated. It's just not clear what three keys are assigned to? I have been through shortcuts of system and all running apps but it shows noone use these keys together...?

Comment: Like @Tetsujin said, those keys *are not assigned to ANYTHING.* That is why you get the error beep. Apple does not use the control key the same way Windows or Linux does, as a keyboard shortcut. Apple uses COMMAND and OPTION, so if you have not added an app that can assign CTRL shortcut keys and there are none in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts then it has not been assigned.

Comment: @SteveChambers  I appreciate what you are saying, but for over two years using Apps Script on Chrome on my Mac the control + / has acted to comment /uncomment code.  During this time my Mac has never made a sound... The last week I get this sound whilst using Apps Script in Chrome...

Comment: @andy see this is where providing full and complete information in your question is **CRITICAL.** We were responding to the Mac and macOS beeping at a CTRL/. You, however, were referring to a problem with Google Chrome on a Mac. Those are two entirely different things as some apps **do** use the CTRL key for some functions, it's just not standard Mac usage. Please edit your question to reflect that the issue is in Google Chrome on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question, however, to prevent it from being buried, I figured I'd add it in. I've been messing around with setting up more windows-like shortcuts for my mac, VS code, etc, and ran into this issue.

Couldn't actually figure out why this sound was playing, so just decided to disable it. To do so: Preferences > Sound > Play user interface sound effects (make sure this setting is off).